# My pagination is not working in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have facing a problem in my codeigniter controller this pagination code is not working properly:

```
function index()
{
    $data['title'] = "Hope Center - Home";

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Home';

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->donation_model->get_search_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pager">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="rounds">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="rounds active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="previous">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="rounds disabled">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="rounds">';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
    $this->pagination->initialize();
    $data['donation_info'] = $this->donation_model->get_donation_info($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('frontend/layouts/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/home',$data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/layouts/footer');
}
```

I have added the full controller function code in above.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: - What version of CodeIgniter are you using?  
- What's the result when you print 'get_search_count()'?  
- What error(s) are you getting on page?

Comment: I am using Codeigniter 3.1.8. The result is the total rows of that table. Error is totally not working my full code.

Comment: Have you left out the class constructor containing the library? as the Answer below suggests? What do you get when you print this: $home = base_url().'Home';

Comment: I found two things missing library and base_url function name. But Is this corrent `Home/index` index is my function

Comment: Still pagination is not working. I think the problem is initialization. Can you please check this out?